# How can I isolate cookies on a same server?

Tags: php, webserver, session-state, session-cookies

I have 2 Websites on a same server Host . I want to Isolate cookies of Site 1 from Site 2 . How can I Do that ?

I don't want to spend money and want to host both sites on the same  server.But Cookies of one site should not interfere with the others.

My Directory structure is as (I am flexible to change this , the main aim is to have both on the same server)

```
 www.mysite.com/       - website 1st
 www.mysite.com/site2  - website2nd
```

Both have different code and are not related to each other. Currently just placed in different directory.  when I `echo $_SESSION['id']`  from the 2nd interfere with the St.

Comment: your definition of site is a different directory ? when you create cookie you can set a path, it's he the 4th var

Comment: @Dagon - Yes , Both have different code and are not related to each other. Currently just placed in different directory.  when I `echo $_SESSION['id']`  from the 2nd interfere with the St.

Comment: sessions or cookies? they are not the same thing

Comment: @Dagon - I mean with these `echo $_SESSION['id']`  lines .

Comment: the easy option would be to set the site in the session (multi dimensional array) ie `$_SESSION['site1']['id']='1';` etc

Comment: @Dagon I don't Know what the difference is ?  :/  . These  `echo $_SESSION['id']` are cookies or sessions ? I want these to be separated from each other. What are sub-domains ? Are they Isolated ?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies have a path associated with them, but when the path is a directory it applies to the entire hierarchy within it as well. The problem you're having is that Site 2 is in a subdirectory of Site 1.

So you need to put the two sites in disjoint directories:

Site 1: www.mysite.com/site1
Site 2: www.mysite.com/site2

Another option is to use virtual hosts. Cookies are associated with the server hostname, so you could have www.mysite1.com and www.mysite2.com. Then the actual location on the server doesn't matter.

Comment: So if Site 1: www.mysite.com/site1 Site 2: www.mysite.com/site2 then in this case the `echo $_SESSION['id']` on site 2 wont interfere with site 1 ? Am I correct ?

Comment: What are sub-domains ? Are they Isolated ?

Comment: When you create a cookie, you can assign it to either `www.mysite.com` or `.www.mysite.com`. In the first case it only applies to that exact domain. The second case applies to the domain and all sub-domains.

Comment: So isn't there any alternative which will isolate the result of `echo $_SESSION['id']` on both different sites ?

Comment: See [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) for how to control the cookie used for `$_SESSION`.